# Describe the product scheme $\text{Spec } k(s) \times_{\text{Spec } k} \text{Spec } k(t)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand this Hartshorne exercise II.3.9(b):

> Describe the product scheme $\text{Spec } k(s) \times_{\text{Spec } k} \text{Spec } k(t)$

The purpose of these exercise is to see that the product of the underlying set is not the same as the underlying set of the fibred product.

I see that $\text{Spec } k(s) \times_{\text{Spec } k} \text{Spec } k(t) = \text{Spec } k(s) \otimes k(t)$ but if the ring $k(s) \otimes k(t)$ is still a field, why wouldn't the underlying space of the product be again just a point?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. Thanks!

Comment: $k(s) \otimes_k k(t)$ is not a field. It is explicitly described in Example 6.9 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf

Comment: @MooS Wow thanks! This example is very clear. I'm trying to deduce what the Spec of the tensor in the following way: Since $\text{Spec }(k(x) \otimes k(y)) = \text{Spec } (T^{-1} k[x, y])$ where $T$ is the multiplicative system that contains all elements in $F[x, y]$ that cannot be factored in the form of $a(x)b(y)$. Then the non-units of the local ring $T^{-1}k[x, y]$ contains elements like $(a-xy), (a+x^2 y), (x^2 + xy + y^2)...$. These are the irreducible and reduced plain curves? Are these all the prime ideals? Many thanks again!

Comment: Maybe the wonderful note by K. Conrad had been edited, and the corresponding example to this post is now Example 7.9 in the note, instead of Example 6.9